# Implicit conversion to a C++ template object

Tags: c++

I have a class A:

```
template <typename T, int I> struct A {};
```

and a class B. I would like object's of type B to implicitly convert to A when given as function arguments. B looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct B {
  operator A<T,0> &() const { return *new A<T,0>(); }
};
```

However, my test (below) fails with GCC 4.5, giving the error: *no matching function for call to 'test(B&)'* Where am I going wrong here? Do other compilers also reject this?

```
template <typename T, int I>
void test(A<T,I> &a) { delete &a; }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  B<int> b;
  test(b);
  return 0;
}
```

p.s. I've now put my own solution in an answer below.

Comment: I would point out the memory leak, but it looks as though this was just put together to showcase the issue, so I won't.  I will upvote instead.  :-)

Comment: `test<int,0>(b);` should work fine.

Comment: @user: Yes, since the compiler has no way to infer that you wanted `I` to be `0`, you must specify it explicitly.

Comment: Is this also to do with whether the destinations of implicit conversions participate in template argument deduction? I think they don't, it's just based on the type of the argument expression, so `test(b)` can only refer to an instantiation of the function template which takes a `B<int>` (or reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an implicit conversion from B to A you would need either:

A cast operator on B:

```
operator A<T,0>();
```

or an A constructor which takes a B reference:

```
A( const B& other );
```

or for B to derive from A. What you have declared:

```
operator A<T,0> &() const;
```

looks a bit like an ill-declared address-of overload.

However, since test() takes a reference (and non-const at that), the casting operator option won't work.

This is what I've tested:

```
template <typename T, int I> struct A {};

template <typename T>
struct B {
  //operator A<T,0> &() const { return *new A<T,0>(); }

    template< int I >
    operator A<T, I> () const { return A< T, 0 >(); }
};

template <typename T, int I>
void test(A<T,I> &) { }

int f()
{
  B<int> b;

  A<int, 0> a( b );
  test(a); // <-- Success

  test(b); // <-- Failure, "could not deduce template argument"
  return 0;
}
```

Conversion to A by initialising a local variable works fine.

Comment: To paraphrase in a hand-waving way: Since test() takes a non-const reference to an A, you need to pass it something with type A that it can change. Since B isn't derived from A, nothing you can declare in B will let you do this implicitly.

Comment: I've never done it, but I think it's possible to declare a conversion operator that returns 'A<...> &' if typedef is used. Of course, for this to be useful, B needs to have a non-const instance of A in it.

Answer (score 3):

Unrelated to your problem but `return *new A<T,0>();` is wrong since it <del>leaks memory</del>invites a memory leak. You should *not* use `new` here. `return A<T, 0>();` and removing the reference from the return type works just fine and does not leak memory.

Comment: Thanks Konrad. I believe that would force me to make test accept only const reference arguments?

Comment: `test` takes its parameter by non-const reference, which is even more confusing (if it wants to modify its parameter).

Comment: @user643722 True. You could overload it though.

Comment: What memory leak?  One object is allocated, returned by reference, and deleted.  No copy is made, the same address is deleted as was originally allocated.  I would prefer returning a pointer of course, but the current code is correct if confusing.

Comment: @Ben Duh. I didn’t see the deletion (originally I didn’t see the reference return type either). OK, no memory leak.

Comment: @Konrad: Actually, looking at the timestamps, I think it might have been a ninja edit.

Comment: @Konrad: For me this is closest to an answer now: I'm able to use C++0x, and so your conversion operator, and an Rvalue reference on test's argument is looking good. I'll write it up shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you actually want such an implicit conversion here? It sounds like a perfect way to confuse yourself or another maintainer, or worse, call a function using the wrong argument because the implicit conversion allows it. Instead, consider a `make_A` template like `std::make_pair` to explicitly show your intention at the call site.

Comment: Thanks Mark. The code is automatically generated and, once a solution is found, will not be modified by end users.

Comment: @user643722 Then that's even more of a reason to use the explicit call since it's automatically generated. Presumably humans still have to read the code.

Answer (score 1):

Providing an overload of `test` like the following will enable to write
`test(b)` as in the question.
For example:

```
template <typename T>
void test(B<T> const &b) {
  test( static_cast< A<T,0>& >( b ) );
}

test(b); // caller
```

If such overload isn't allowed but you are allowed to modify `B`'s
definition, how about providing member function which returns `A`
like the following, instead of conversion function?

```
template <typename T>
struct B {
  A<T,0> &to_A() const { return *new A<T,0>(); }
};

test( b.to_A() );
```

If you aren't allowed to modify `B`'s definition, the above `to_A` will be
a free function like the following instead of member function:

```
template <typename T>
A<T,0> &to_A(B<T> const &b) {
  return static_cast< A<T,0>& >( b );
}

test( to_A( b ) );
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This fails in VC++ too.  To make it work, add this method:

```
template <typename T>
void test(B<T> &b)
{
   test( static_cast< A<T,0>& > (b) );
}
```

This will take an actual `B`, explicitly do the conversion (via `static_cast`), and then call `test` using the `A` we just made.

I get errors when I run it though.  I hope this is just example code, and you're not doing `delete &a` in your actual code.  RobH gave a better conversion operator for you, and avoids the pointer messiness.

Comment: You probably should cast it to a reference: `static_cast<A<T, 0>&>(b)`, otherwise a copy is made which test tries to delete.

Comment: D'oh!  Yep that fixes my problem.  Good catch, @UncleBens

Answer (score 0):

I've settled on using the pass by value conversion operator suggested by Konrad; the explicit template function call of Let_Me_Be; and I sprinkled a little bit of C++0x magic on top: an rvalue reference on the parameter to test. (Or, should that be C++ 2011 now?)

```
template <typename T, int I> struct A { int x; };

template <typename T>
struct B {
  operator A<T,0> () const { return A<T,0>(); }
};

template <typename T, int I>
void test(A<T,I> &&a) { a.x=7; printf("%d\n", x); }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  B<int> b;
  test<int,0>(b);
  return 0;
}
```